# Views items not associated with a menu

Tags: drupal

I have a news page that is a View that dynamically pulls in the latest news nodes.  The actual view page was easily integrated into the menu. We are using the menu block module because we have the navigation split.

The problem is that any of the articles that the news view pulls in aren't associated with a menu, so when navigated to the menu block disappears.

How can we associate those items dynamically without having to manually add all news nodes as sub-items to the news page?

(We are on drupal 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context module ([drupal.org/project/context](http://drupal.org/project/context)) allows you to create contexts based conditions, including path or node type, as well as reactions, such as displaying blocks or menus. You could set the context to your node type, and then create a reaction that displays your menus, sidebars etc.

Comment: That's a possible solution.  I'm assuming that it won't keep the breadcrumb trail though, am I right?

Comment: Context can be used to set breadcrumbs and menu active states. May also want to checkout Menu Position.

Comment: I know this is old, but wanted it to be up to date...context can work, but I found Menu Position to work great for our project